# NNer Jahre vs. NNer-Jahre: Ist stilistischer oder semantischer Unterschied vorhanden?

Tags: hyphen

Gibt es einen stilistischen oder semantischen Unterschied, ob man den Bindestrich in NNer-Jahre auslässt oder benutzt, also ob man

> 60er Jahre, Mitte 60er Jahre, 80er und 90er Jahre

oder

> 60er-Jahre, Mitte 60er-Jahre, 80er- und 90er-Jahre

schreibt?  So viel ich verstehe, lassen die Rechtschreibregeln 2018 in § 42 (s. [Beispiel direkt nach § 42](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6159#par42)) beides zu:

> in den 80er-Jahren (auch in den 80er Jahren)

. Eventuell könnte es da einen semantischen Unterschied geben, je nachdem ob man das Zeitintervall 1980 A.D. – 1989 A.D. oder den Lebensabschnitt eines Menschen, in dem er zuerst 80 und am Ende (hoffentlich) 89 wird, meint.

Comment: Ich denke, wenn sich schon die Beispiele zum §42 nicht an die Regel halten, solltest wenigstens du es tun ;). Die Beispiele zeigen ein *Vorkommen* an - setzen aber nicht die Regel außer Kraft.

Comment: Es gibt unter "Fragen und Antworten" eine weitere Erklärung zu Ziffernfolgen mit Nachsilben. Dort kommt eine solche Ausnahme nicht vor.

Answer (score 3):

## Methodologie

In meinen Augen birgt ein vorschnelles Abgleiten in normative Kategorien die Gefahr, den Blick zu verstellen. Aufgrund der Tatsache, dass beide Schreibweisen verbreitet sind, kann man nicht einfach von *falsch* und *richtig* sprechen. Erkenntnis kommt hier nur aus einer unbefangenen Beschreibung des Phänomens. Um die Frage nach semantischen Unterschieden zu beantworten, ist es zunächst einmal hilfreich, die unterschiedliche Morphologie zu beschreiben und grammatisch einzuordnen. Wenn es sich um grammatische unterschiedliche Formen handelt, könnten mit der jeweiligen Form unterschiedliche Bedeutungsnuancen einhergehen.

Ich habe kein besonderes Wissen, und kann mich nicht auf Quellen berufen. Dennoch versuche ich, die beiden Formen zu analysieren und meine Schlüsse so gut wie möglich zu begründen. Ich versuche dabei, Unsicherheit durch vorsichtige Wortwahl wiederzugeben.

## Phonetischer Unterschied

In meinen Augen unterscheiden sich die beiden Varianten nicht nur im Graphem, sondern auch auf der phonetischen Ebene: *80er Jahre* hat eine stärkere Betonung auf der ersten Silbe (*acht*), während *80er-Jahre* die Betonung eher auf der vierten Silbe (*Jah*) hat. Eine Betonung auf der vierten Silbe scheint mir bei *80er Jahre* geradezu ausgeschlossen.

## Analogien

Eine Möglichkeit, die beiden Formen grammatisch zu vergleichen, besteht darin, analoge Phänomene zu betrachten. Tut man das, so zeigt sich folgendes Bild:

A) *80er Jahre* ist analog zu folgenden Formen:

- *der Potsdamer Platz*
- *die Leipziger Straße*
- *Münchner*

B) *80er-Jahre* ist analog zu folgenden Formen:

- *50er-Banknote*
- *6er-Pasch*

Unterstellt man, dass die jeweiligen Schreibweisen semantische Einflüsse aus den Analoga beziehen, dann muss man sich fragen, wie man die Wortbildung in den Analoga charakterisieren kann, und welche Bedeutungsunterschiede bzw. -nuancen sich daraus ergeben. Ich meine, dass man bei den Analoga folgendes beobachten kann: **Die unter A) aufgeführten Formen drücken Zugehörigkeit aus, die unter B) nicht**:

- *der Potsdamer Platz*: "der zu Potsdam gehörende Platz"
- *die Leipziger Straße*: "die nach Leipzig führende Straße"
- *ein Münchner*: "ein Einwohner Münchens"
- eine *50er-Banknote* ist nicht "die zu den 50 gehörende Banknote", sondern "die Banknote mit der 50"
- ein *6er-Pasch* ist nicht "der zu den Sechsen gehörende Pasch", sondern "der aus Sechsen bzw. aus Sechsern bestehende Pasch"

Die Zusammensetzung mit Bindestrich drückt also nur ganz allgemein eine wie auch immer geartete Verbindung aus, ohne diese als Zugehörigkeit näher zu charakterisieren. Das Suffix hätte demnach im Fall von *80er Jahre* eine andere Funktion als im Fall von *80er-Jahre*.
Diese unterschiedliche Konzeptualisierung würde ich als semantische Nuance bezeichnen, auch wenn sich die jeweiligen Denotate von *80er Jahre* und *80er-Jahre* nicht unterscheiden. Mir scheint aber, dass diese Nuance in der tatsächlichen Verwendung keine Rolle spielt. Für die letzte Aussage kann ich jedoch keine Belege anführen, sondern nur mein "Sprachgefühl".

## Normative Erwägungen

Zu guter Letzt doch noch ein Kommentar zur normativen Frage: Die in der Frage zitierte Regel besagt

> Bilden Verbindungen aus Ziffern und Suffixen den vorderen Teil einer Zusammensetzung, so setzt man nach dem Suffix einen Bindestrich.

Man könnte die Schreibweise *80er Jahre* im Angesicht dieser Norm als korrekt rechtfertigen, indem man sie eben gerade nicht als Zusammensetzung betrachtet, sodass die Regel hier gar nicht einschlägig ist. Ich halte das für plausibel. Vielleicht ist aber auch nur die Regel ungeeignet, die tatsächliche Sprachpraxis abzubilden. In diesem Fall stellt sich immer die Frage nach der Autorität von irgendwelchen Regeln, die irgendjemand aufgestellt hat.

Comment: @user0 Could you specify what it is that you are unsure to believe? Maybe I can improve my answer.

Comment: (+1) Gute Analyse.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied ist keine Frage des Stils, sondern eine Frage von *richtig oder falsch*. So besagt der von Ihnen angeführte § 42 des [amtlichen Regelwerks (2018)](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) unmissverständlich, dass der Bindestrich gesetzt wird; von der Möglichkeit, ihn wegzulassen, steht dort nichts:

> **§ 42** Bilden Verbindungen aus Ziffern und Suffixen den vorderen Teil einer Zusammensetzung, so setzt man nach dem Suffix einen Bindestrich.

Richtig ist demnach:

> 60er-Jahre, Mitte (der) 60er-Jahre, 80er- und 90er-Jahre

---

**Edit:** Angeregt durch ein Kommentar und einer Änderung der Frage, möchte ich auf das Beispiel mit den *80er Jahren* unter § 42 eingehen. Offensichtlich wird diese Wortfolge nicht als ein einzelnes, zusammengesetztes Wort betrachtet, sondern als zwei Wörter. Damit ist die Bedingung von § 42 nicht erfüllt, weshalb dort kein Bindestrich steht.

Comment: Ich gebe zu, dass ich das Beispiel nicht nachvollziehen kann. Nichtsdestotrotz ist es irrelevant. Grundlage für die Regeln sind die Paragraphen; die Beispiele dienen nur zur Veranschaulichung (oder, wie in diesem Fall, der Verwirrung).

Comment: @user0 Dieses Beispiel wird mit "auch" genannt - Das heißt so viel wie "gibt's, aber ist trotzdem falsch".

Comment: Ich vermute eher, dass es zu §42 noch eine Alternative gibt, wo *80er* **nicht den vorderen Teil einer Zusammensetung bildet** and daher keinen Bindestrich erfordert. Daher beide Beispiele.

Comment: @user0 Kann sein. Vielleicht will ich auch einfach nicht, dass man den Bindestrich weglassen darf - Mir rollen sich dabei die Fußnägel hoch. Das Beispiel darunter (das ausgeschriebene) weist allerdings in derselben Klammer darauf hin. Was *achtziger* allerdings für eine Wortart sein soll, ist mir schleierhaft. Duden meint, es sei ein Substantiv (Pluralwort). Warum schreibt man es dann klein?

Comment: Die Frage fragt nach einem semantischen oder stilistischen Unterschied - also dezidiert nach einer deskriptiven Aussage, du antwortest mit einer normativen Aussage. Das verfehlt die Frage, daher gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: @user0 »Bei Ziffern "80" gibt es nicht groß/klein«: [doch](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediävalziffer) aber sie erfüllen nicht die selbe Funktion.

Comment: OK, Ich hatte übersehen, dass die Frage zwischenzeitlich editiert worden war. Björn, wenn du einen minor Edit machst, kann ich mein negatives Votum zurücknehmen.